# How to get all elements on different types of diagonal lines of 2D list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have an input as 2D list of strings. Somewhere in this list are two zeroes making some diagonal line (always +-45 deg)
I need to get all elements on the diagonals.

Example:
INPUT:

```
['xxxxtbnxxxx',
 'xnadgpenmen',
 'xuebaturekt',
 'ncnkbendx0x',
 'apadzrzolxm',
 'kalilabubxa',
 'rlxxxxrebar',
 'yseakirejcg',
 'skok0soxneo',
 'xosrozsevsr',
 'xxxxkwexsnp']
```

OUTPUT:

```
['t', '0', 'l', 'u', 'r', 'i', '0', 'r', 'x']
```

My code doesnt look good and doesn't working, but here it is part for growing and declinig lines, positions of zeroes are in list [x0, y0, x1, y1]

```
def all_elements_diag_grow_line(matrix, positions_of_zeroes):
elements = []
j = len(matrix[0]) - 1
a = int(positions_of_zeroes[1])-(len(matrix[0]) - 1 - int(positions_of_zeroes[0]))
if a < 0:
    a = 0
    j = int(positions_of_zeroes[0])
print("radek zacatku",a,j,"x-sova soradnice 0",int(positions_of_zeroes[0]), "y-sova soradnice 0",int(positions_of_zeroes[1]))
print(len(matrix[0]), int(positions_of_zeroes[0]))
for i in range (a, len(matrix)):
    elements.append(matrix[i][j])
    j-=1
return elements


def all_elements_diag_dec_line(matrix, positions_of_zeroes):
    elements = []
    j = 0
    for i in range (int(positions_of_zeroes[1])-int(positions_of_zeroes[0]), len(matrix)):
        elements.append(matrix[i][j])
        j+=1
    return elements
```

Can anyone please help me with that? My brain doesnt work anymore and my code either

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Please [edit] the question to fix the indenting of your code. See [code formatting help](/editing-help#code) if needed. Also you need to include how you're calling the functions. See [mre] for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't involve scanning the whole grid to print it out:

```
# Locate the 2 0's
zeros = []
for r,line in enumerate(m):
    if '0' in line:
        zeros.append([r,line.index('0')])
# Determine direction to change columns along diagonal as we increase row #
dc = -1 if zeros[1][1] < zeros[0][1] else 1
r,c = zeros[0]
# "Back up" to start of diagonal
while r>0 and c>0 and c<len(m[0])-1:
    r -= 1
    c -= dc
# Fill diag with elements along diagonal, top to bottom
diag = []
while r < len(m) and c >=0 and c < len(m[0]):
    diag.append(m[r][c])
    r += 1 
    c += dc
# Print it!
print(diag)
```